# How to use xxhash-addon with vite

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vite

node:v18.17.0
npm:9.6.7
vue 3
vite

install: cnpm install xxhash-addon

vite.config.ts:

```
optimizeDeps:{
    exclude: ['xxhash-addon']
},
```

use code:

```
import * as XXHash from "xxhash-addon";

if (entry.isFile && "file" in entry) {
        entry.file(
            file => {
                console.log(XXHash.XXHash3.hash(buffer.Buffer.from(entry.fullPath)).toString('hex'));
                // console.log(entry.fullPath);
                // resourcesStore.waitingUpload.push(entry);
            },
            e => {
                console.log("error");
            }
        );
    }
```

and then I got the error：

```
Main.vue:84  ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at xxhash-addon.js?v=1feabdbc:1:1
```

xxhash-addon.js content:

```
module.exports = {
   ...require(process.env.DEBUG === undefined ? './build/Release/addon' : './build/Debug/addon')
};
```

At first,I don't add `optimizeDeps:{exclude: ['xxhash-addon']},` in vite.config.ts 。 and will got another error :

```
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./build/Release/addon"

    node_modules/.store/xxhash-addon@2.0.1/node_modules/xxhash-addon/xxhash-addon.js:2:48:
      2 │    ...require(process.env.DEBUG === undefined ? './build/Release/addon' : './build/Debug/addon')
        ╵                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "./build/Debug/addon"

    node_modules/.store/xxhash-addon@2.0.1/node_modules/xxhash-addon/xxhash-addon.js:2:74:
      2 │    ...require(process.env.DEBUG === undefined ? './build/Release/addon' : './build/Debug/addon')
        ╵                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

D:\web_project\own\companion-admin-web\node_modules\.store\esbuild@0.18.20\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1649
  let error = new Error(`${text}${summary}`);
              ^

Error: Build failed with 2 errors:
node_modules/.store/xxhash-addon@2.0.1/node_modules/xxhash-addon/xxhash-addon.js:2:48: ERROR: Could not resolve "./build/Release/addon"
node_modules/.store/xxhash-addon@2.0.1/node_modules/xxhash-addon/xxhash-addon.js:2:74: ERROR: Could not resolve "./build/Debug/addon"
    at failureErrorWithLog (D:\web_project\own\companion-admin-web\node_modules\.store\esbuild@0.18.20\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1649:15)
    at D:\web_project\own\companion-admin-web\node_modules\.store\esbuild@0.18.20\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1058:25
    at D:\web_project\own\companion-admin-web\node_modules\.store\esbuild@0.18.20\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1525:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 48,
        file: 'node_modules/.store/xxhash-addon@2.0.1/node_modules/xxhash-addon/xxhash-addon.js',
        length: 23,
        line: 2,
        lineText: "   ...require(process.env.DEBUG === undefined ? './build/Release/addon' : './build/Debug/addon')",
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./build/Release/addon"'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 74,
        file: 'node_modules/.store/xxhash-addon@2.0.1/node_modules/xxhash-addon/xxhash-addon.js',
        length: 21,
        line: 2,
        lineText: "   ...require(process.env.DEBUG === undefined ? './build/Release/addon' : './build/Debug/addon')",
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "./build/Debug/addon"'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}
```

then I had install vite-plugin-require-transform and replace `import * as XXHash from "xxhash-addon";` with `const addon = require("xxhash-addon");`, also the error:

```
Main.vue:84  ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at xxhash-addon.js?v=71396354:1:1
```

if I just use .node file ,will get the next error:

```
This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
```

Please tell me how to resolve the problem